# Force a codeigniter custom 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a custom 404 controller. It works fine. In routes.php I have:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'custom404';
```

this accesses this controller:

```
class custom404 extends MasterController {
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){

        $this->output->set_status_header('404');

        $crit = array(
            'subtype' => 'footer',
            'status' => 'public'
        );
        $res = $this->mongo_db->where($crit)->get('contentobjects');



        $this->pagedata = $res[0];

        $this->load->view('404');

    }
}
```

Can I call this from a different controller?
Currently I'm just forcing the issue by calling an (ostensibly) never-extant page:

```
if(!$this->viewable($res[0])){
        header('Location: /404');
        die;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just redirect to it directly.

However CI comes with an errors folder, with a sub folder for HTML and a 404 error view page. If you customize this page all your headers will be set correctly automatically, and you can call it in a much clearer manner.

```
if (empty($result))
{
    // show error
    show_error('The result you requested could not be found', '404');
}
```

Or more concisely:

```
if (empty($result)) show_error('The result you requested could not be found', '404');
```

The message here can be accessed in the template with $message field.

You can then easily set any code you need, like 401 etc.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html

Comment: This does throw a 404, but without my custom 404 view.

Comment: You can then customise the error templates that come in your default error views folder.